# SSRS colour formatting expression works in Report builder but not in Browser

Tags: browser, reporting-services, background-color, sql-server-2016, reportbuilder

I have a report created in SQl Server Report Builder.
Text boxes in the Report have a background Color fill based on the below expression

```
=IIF(FIRST(Fields!idsite.Value, "DataSet_AuctionSite")=6, "SeaGreen", IIF(FIRST(Fields!idsite.Value, "DataSet_AuctionSite")=8, "SeaGreen",IIF(FIRST(Fields!idsite.Value, "DataSet_AuctionSite")=9, "SeaGreen", "Brown")))
```

When I run the report in Report Builder, it appears correctly. SeaGreen background if the idSite equals 6,8 or 9, Brown if anything else.

But when I save the report & view it in a web browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox), the background colour is white/clear

I can't figure it, any tips appreciated
using SQl server 2016 Reporting Services

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it will make a difference but you can use SWITCH conditional function instead

```
=Switch(
    Fields!idsite.Value = 6, "SeaGreen",
    Fields!idsite.Value = 8, "SeaGreen",
    Fields!idsite.Value = 9, "SeaGreen",
    true, "Brown"
)
```

Comment: Same outcome unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with SQL Server 2016 and SSRS.

See the following Cumulative Update for SQL Server 2016

[Cumulative Update 1 for SQL Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3170528/the-backgroundcolor-property-is-%20not-respected-when-it-is-specified-by)

Regards

Craig